# Order of categoricals in seaborn PairGrid

Tags: python, seaborn, categorical-data

I'm mapping the seaborn stripplot to a seaborn PairGrid using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = (pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/' +
              'Rdatasets/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv')
    .drop(labels='Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    .astype(dtype={'cut': 'category', 'color': 'category',
                   'clarity': 'category'}))
agged = df.groupby(by=['cut', 'color']).mean().sort_index().reset_index()
g = sns.PairGrid(data=agged, x_vars=agged.columns[2:], y_vars=['cut', 'color'],
             size=5, aspect=.65)
g.map(func=sns.stripplot, orient='h', size=10, palette='Blues_d')
```

By default, the categories in the 'cut' facets are displaying in alphabetical order. However, I want to specify the order:

```
['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal']
```

I've tried passing the 'order' parameter for stripplot as follows:

```
g.map(func=sns.stripplot, orient='h', size=10, palette='Blues_d',
  order=['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal'])
```

Although this correctly sorts the categories in 'cut', it results in nothing being plotted in the 'color' facets at all. I've also tried specifying the 'color' facet ordering in the same parameter as follows:

```
g.map(func=sns.stripplot, orient='h', size=10, palette='Blues_d',
  order=['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal', 'D', 'E', 'F',
         'G', 'H', I'])
```

However, the problem here is that all of the values in the order parameter appear in both the 'color' and 'cut' facets.

Is it possible to specify an ordering in the mapping function that results in the correct ordering in both sets of facets, with no duplications?

```
['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal']
['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', I']
```

Comment: I've tried to amend my original post to make it minimal, complete & verifiable by including the code that reads my original df (which is the sample diamonds dataset from ggplot2). Hopefully this will help. Sorry - I'm new to asking questions here, so please bear with me as I keep trying to be clear!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have different categories for each row in the grid. Hence you would need a different `order` for the subplots from each row.

I don't think that there is an automatic way to supply the different orders, but you may define your own dictionary of orders depending on row variables

```
order = {'cut'  :['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal'],
         'color':['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']}
```

Then you may map a custom function to the grid, which selects the correct order, depending on the row variable.

```
def ordered_stripplot(*args, **kwargs):
    order = kwargs.pop("order")
    sns.stripplot(args[0],args[1], order=order[args[1].name], **kwargs)

g.map(ordered_stripplot, order=order, orient='h', size=10, palette='Blues_d')
```

Instead of mapping directly to `sns.stripplot` you map to a custom function, which takes the order dictionary as input and selects, depending on the argument, the correct order. This is supplied to `sns.stripplot`, being called within this function.

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = (pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer='http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/' +
              'Rdatasets/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv')
    .drop(labels='Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
    .astype(dtype={'cut': 'category', 'color': 'category',
                   'clarity': 'category'}))
agged = df.groupby(by=['cut', 'color']).mean().sort_index().reset_index()

order = {'cut'  :['Fair', 'Good', 'Very Good', 'Premium', 'Ideal'],
         'color':['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']}

g = sns.PairGrid(data=agged, x_vars=agged.columns[2:], y_vars=['cut', 'color'],
             size=3, aspect=.65)

def ordered_stripplot(*args, **kwargs):
    order = kwargs.pop("order")
    sns.stripplot(args[0],args[1], order=order[args[1].name], **kwargs)

g.map(ordered_stripplot, order=order, orient='h', size=10, palette='Blues_d')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's a really useful technique, and I can see how it could form a design pattern for similar requirements. I'd reached the same conclusion as you, that it was unlikely to be possible to supply different orders, but I was struggling to see the solution of wrapping the stripplot with a custom function and using a dictionary for the orders. Very elegant.I've up-voted your answer, but as I don't have enough reputation yet, it's still displaying as 0.